# Notify the parent job that all sub job have finished?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a job let's call it the parent job

```
ParentJob::dispatch()
```

at this Job I am dispatching sub jobs like so:

```
function handle(){
  for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ;  i ++ ) 
     SubJob::dispatch()
//notify that all sub job has finished
```

Would you prefer using other software for complex queue job ? (E.g: Celery )

Answer (score 0):

Unless you query your database (or any other queue driver) until the jobs are done, you can't.

You could however run the subjobs on the `sync` driver. This will run the jobs on the current thread so the code won't continue until the job is done. The disadvantage of this is that only one subjob will run at a time.

```
function handle() 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5;  i++) {
        SubJob::dispatch()->onConnection('sync');
    }

    echo "Done!";
}
```

Comment: No I need to know when all the subjob finished when they run asyncrounously